# np.random.multinomial without zero in it

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to generate a list of n size whose sum is equal to m, I have chosen np.random.multinomial for this but it is generating 0 in the list, is there a way to exclude 0 from this list, is there so solution for this, or do I need to brute force this i.e keep generating lists until it gives me a list without zero in it?

Sample is:

```
N = 6
M = 2*N+1
np.random.multinomial(M, np.ones(N) / N)
```

Which gives me:

```
[1 6 0 1 3]
```

Comment: How about `np.random.multinomial(M - N, np.ones(N) / N) + np.ones(N, dtype=int)`

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser can you elaborate on this ?

Comment: It is a multinomial with sum M - N, plus 1 added to each element.